# Fetch firebase nested subcollections for multiple documents with 'where'

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a simple web application and want to fetch 10 particular posts replies at a time by their postIds.

I'm using Firebase firestore, here is my database design
`posts/{postDocument}/replies/{replyDocument}.`

Reply here is a document inside a collection `replies` which contains into a document `post`

My use case is that I want to fetch 10 posts at a time and so for each post also its subcollection (replies)

If I do a loop like `for each postDocumentId await fetchReplies(postDocumentId)` it will take too much time for one iteration (10 iterations overall)

I want to achieve something like this:

```
  let postIds = [ '123', '321', '221','123', '021', '621','423', '521', '291','251' ]
  let snapshot = await firestore()
          .collection('posts/replies')
          .where('postId', 'in', postIds)
          .get();
```

In the end I want to get data from firebase the most optimal way and get it in this type:

```
[{post:{...},
replies:[{...},{...}]},
{post:{...},
replies:[{...},{...}]},
{post:{...},
replies:[{...},{...}]},
{post:{...},
replies:[{...},{...}]},
{post:{...},
replies:[{...},{...}]}]
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read documents from all `replies` collections with a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

But there's no way to limit that to the `replies` collections under a specific set of document IDs, unless those document IDs are also in the `replies` documents.

Comment: thank you! 
maybe you know what if I make one collection group query with 1000 results how many reads would be considered from firebase side? in terms of pricing

Comment: It will be counted at 1000 reads

Comment: so each result in firebase .get() is a 1 read?
for instance if I fetch 3 objects of users through one .get() it will count as 3 reads?

Comment: For pricing, I find it easiest to take the from the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) name literally: since you're charged for **document reads**, reading 1,000 documents from the database counts as 1,000 document reads (unless they come from the local cache, but that seems less likely here).